# How do you deploy Maven project from Github to Heroku automatically?

Tags: maven, github, heroku

So I have a Maven project and I'd like to deploy it on Heroku via Github. To be more precise I want to use automatic deployments where when I push to my master branch only then is it deployed. The only thing I found for Maven is that I add a dependency and it would deploy to Heroku from my machine (which I essentially don't want).

I really don't know what else to say as I had 0 progress. For now I am just pushing my target as well and then just running the target jar file. But I'd like to just send over my source code and for Heroku to build the project.

Comment: Take a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Comment: Well it's not that I don't know how to use automatic deploy, it was really easy with Phoenix applications but I'm having issues with maven as it just doesn't do anything. 

I made a workaround for those deployments by pushing the target .jar file as well but it should be possible with only the source code.

Comment: Can't you just define a setup script on heroku that creates the JAR?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know exactly how! I did use Maven but only the integrated version of IntelliJ idea.

Comment: What does "I'm having issues with maven as it just doesn't do anything" mean?

Comment: Well I had the problem that heroku would just say that it has been build but it didn't actually do anything, there were no logs after 'build completed' (which didn't really create the `target` folder). But, again, I did manage to find a workaround by making the Procfile build and run the project.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to integrate your GitHub repository on Heroku, and define the automated deployment of the master branch (each push will trigger a deployment).

Heroku will build the JAR and take care of the deployment, you need though to define the Java version in a `system.properties` and create an Uber-Jar (ie including all dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found my solution.

I saw an example (I can't find it now, no luck) for Heroku that build the project with a thing called mvnw script which is a Maven wrapper when it's not installed on the system. I added it and the .mvn directory but it didn't start by itself like how it is written on Heroku (it should run it when it's detected), no problem really.

I then edited my Procfile and instead of:

```
web: java -jar target/my-file.jar
```

I am using:

```
web: ./mvnw clean package; java -jar target/my-file.jar
```

And everything works well!